# Mouse pointer always "in work"

Tags: qgis-3

I used QGIS 3.2 Bonn and suddenly, and I don´t know why, the mouse pointer never stops rotating as the project is in work. It is still possible to click and select things like it is possible with the arrow pointer.[image]
I installed the new version 3.6 now but the pointer remains busy. I deleted the folders c:/user/computer/.qgis but the pointer is still busy.
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: you should give more infos: OS-System etc.

Comment: o.k. I work with windows 7, 64 bit, any more information?

Comment: Is your project fully loaded ?

Comment: Yes, the project is loaded 100%

Comment: Did you find a solution for the spinning cursor? I currently have the same problem with 3.2 and 3.4 and can't find the solution.

Comment: No, sadly not. I have still no idea of the reason.

Comment: I deleted the plugin osm place search and eversince my cursor is normal again. I have no idea if the file is linked to that.

Comment: o.k. that seems to be similar to my fault...sadly not consistent because I still have the osm place search plugin but no problem. Maybe some compatibility problems?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/160574)

Comment: It was ment as a comment, tried to give an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a reason for the spinning cursor.The failure is in the file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS\qgis3.ini When I create a new profile (Menu/Settings/user profile/new profile) the cursor in the new profile is o.k. Sadly in this file all the settings are saved and if you copy it to the default profile you have to adapt everything. So I copied the file and renamed it to old_qgis3.ini. Then started qgis which created a new ini_file. After a couple of testings the spinning seems to be caused by some plugins. When I deactivated some plugins (with the original ini_file) the corsor stops running. This was sadly not consistent, but with a bit of try and error it works for me. I additionally deleted a online routing mapper plugin. The settings were saved and it works for me...